# How do I remove the character ? from a log file name?

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a log filed created by ansible each time a playbook is run. Not sure as to why there's a ? inserted.

getcpu_and_mem_lin?2020-08-25.log

How do I remove the ? in the file?

How would I add a . in place of the ? instead?

Some background:
I have a shell wrapper for ansible to give me a new log file with the playbook name and date/time with an alias in my .bashrc.

ansible-playbook-wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/home/myuser/log/$(echo $1 | cut -d . -f 1 && date "+%Y-%m-%d").log

ansible-playbook $@
```

In my .bashrc

```
alias ansible-playbook="/home/myuser/ansible-playbook-wrapper.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How would I add a . in place of the ?"*

Short answer: Separate the commands and put the dot between them

```sh
$(echo $1 | cut -d . -f 1).$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
```

---

The first parameter of the wrapper shall be the playbook file. Let's replace `$1` with `playbook.yml` and test it

```sh
shell> echo playbook.yml | cut -d . -f 1 && date "+%Y-%m-%d"
playbook
2020-08-26
```

This gave us 2 lines. This is not what we want. Let's test the environment variable

```sh
shell> export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/home/myuser/log/$(echo playbook.yml | cut -d . -f 1 && date "+%Y-%m-%d").log

shell> echo $ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH
/home/myuser/log/playbook 2020-08-26.log
```

Because of the new line, there is space between `playbook` and `2020-08-26`. Let's fix it and run the commands separately

```sh
shell> export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/home/myuser/log/$(echo playbook.yml | cut -d . -f 1)$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log

shell> echo $ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH
/home/myuser/log/playbook2020-08-26.log
```

Good. There is no space. Let's make it more readable and put a dot '.' between `playbook` and `2020-08-26`

```sh
shell> export ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=/home/myuser/log/$(echo playbook.yml | cut -d . -f 1).$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").log

shell> echo $ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH
/home/myuser/log/playbook.2020-08-26.log
```